# logging makeRecord() takes 8 positional arguments but 11 were given

Tags: python, logging, python-3.5

***Fixed***: Check the repo here - https://github.com/plantpark/python-redis-log Thanks for [lilydjwg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/296473/lilydjwg)'s help

Source code [python-redis-log](https://github.com/jedp/python-redis-log/tree/master/redislog)

[logger.py source code](https://github.com/jedp/python-redis-log/blob/master/redislog/logger.py)

[handlers.py source code](https://github.com/jedp/python-redis-log/blob/master/redislog/handlers.py)

The python-redis-log seems there isn't anyone to maintain. It's not compatible with python3.5 now. I want to migrate it to python3.5. Question here is:

When I run the code shows below. It returns a TypeError " makeRecord() takes 8 positional arguments but 11 were given".

```
# redis_log.py  the same directory with handlers.py and logger.py
import handlers, logger
l = logger.RedisLogger('my.logger')
l.addHandler(handlers.RedisHandler.to("my:channel", host='localhost', port=6379, password='foobie'))
l.info("I like pie")
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "redis_log.py", line 6, in <module>
    l.error("I like pie")
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/logging/__init__.py", line 1309, in error
    self._log(ERROR, msg, args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/logging/__init__.py", line 1415, in _log
    exc_info, func, extra, sinfo)
TypeError: makeRecord() takes 8 positional arguments but 11 were given
```

As the error reported , 11 positional arguments were given . Checked the code again and again, I thought there were something wrong with the code below. But when I comment some keys and values such as,username and name, kept it to 9 arguments. The error kept the same.  So... where is the bug? how to locate it and fix it?

```
# https://github.com/jedp/python-redis-log/blob/master/redislog/logger.py
# python-redis-log logger.py line 71  
    self._raw = {
        #'name': name,
        'level': levelAsString(lvl),
        'filename': fn,
        'line_no': self.lineno,
        'msg': str(msg),
        'args': list(args),
        'time': datetime.datetime.utcnow(),
        'funcname': self.funcname,
        #'username': self.username,
        'hostname': self.hostname,
        'traceback': exc_info
    }
```

Comment: I'm not clear where `makeRecord` is in the code you posted

Comment: @doctorlove pasted logger.py and handlers.py link here directly . check it again. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually get this with Python 3.6.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "redis_log.py", line 4, in <module>
    l.info("I like pie")
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 1306, in info
    self._log(INFO, msg, args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 1441, in _log
    exc_info, func, extra, sinfo)
TypeError: makeRecord() takes from 8 to 10 positional arguments but 11 were given
```

Your definition:

```
def makeRecord(self, name, lvl, fn, lno, msg, args, exc_info, func=None, extra=None):
```

As you can count, there are 11 arguments, two of them have default values.

What does `l.info` call? It calls `self._log` as the traceback shows. The code is like this:

```
def _log(self, level, msg, args, exc_info=None, extra=None, stack_info=False):
    # ...
    record = self.makeRecord(self.name, level, fn, lno, msg, args,
                             exc_info, func, extra, sinfo)
```

This is where your `makeRecord` gets called (by the logging module). Count them. 10 in the parenthesis, and one is passed implicitly because this is a method call (the `self` arg).

You missed the last one. Since you are passing the arguments, you'd better make it extensible like this:

```
def makeRecord(self, name, lvl, fn, lno, msg, args, exc_info, *args, **extra):
    record = RedisLogRecord(name, lvl, fn, lno, msg, args, exc_info, *args, **extra)
```

Also note that your code passes `func=None` to the constructor regardless of your argument `func`.

In your `RedisLogRecord` you can pass `**extra` along to your `self._raw` dict by `self._raw.update(extra)`. For the positional `args`, you need to handle them accordingly.